# Strange clangd crash when using \n instead of endl with -std=c++2a

Tags: c++, vim, c++20, youcompleteme, clangd

This is the reference source file

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int x = 7;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

If I open a line ***before*** the line with `cout` and write `std::` I correctly see YCM's semantic cmpletion popup; if I do the same ***after*** the line with `cout`, I get a `ResponseAbortedException: Response Aborted` error.

`:YcmDebugInfo` gives

```
Printing YouCompleteMe debug information...
-- Resolve completions: Up front
-- Client logfile: /tmp/ycm_fiumsvcv.log
-- Server Python interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
-- Server Python version: 3.8.6
-- Server has Clang support compiled in: True
-- Clang version: clang version 10.0.0 (https://github.com/ycm-core/llvm 038587147cf2f97d1c3e677042f69560c65b5bea)
-- Extra configuration file found and loaded
-- Extra configuration path: /home/enrico/.ycm_extra_conf.py
-- C-family completer debug information:
--   Clangd not running
--   Clangd executable: ['/home/enrico/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/clangd/output/bin/clangd', '-cross-file-rename', '-header-insertion-decorators=0', '-resource-dir=/home/enrico/.vim/plugged/YouCom
pleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/clang/lib/clang/10.0.0', '-limit-results=500']
--   Clangd logfiles:
--     /tmp/clangd_stderryqofwzop.log
--   Clangd Server State: Dead
--   Clangd Project Directory: /home/enrico
--   Clangd Settings: {}
--   Clangd Compilation Command: ['clang-tool', '-x', 'c++', '-std=c++2a', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror', '/home/enrico/deleteme.cpp']
-- Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:42807
-- Server process ID: 25037
-- Server logfiles:
--   /tmp/ycmd_42807_stdout_9pmpk9zp.log
--   /tmp/ycmd_42807_stderr_iat9y0gn.log
```

[This is a screencast](https://asciinema.org/a/0hRAvkePSMq3Ht60epsiCuZ7W) of the issue.

Comment: Clang hasn't caught up (yet) with the C++20 implementation thus far as compared to gcc and msvc. Having the tools such as Clangd work on the latest standard is a far-fetched goal at the most. Let go of Clang and use the other compilers which have caught up the C++20 standards.

Comment: I see you're using Clang 10. Try 11.

Comment: @Jerry: Lack of C++20 support does not make sense to me as an explanation for the crash. The example code does not use any C++20 features, and the standard library headers that come with the compiler do not use any C++20 features that the compiler does not support. (Even if it's using a different compiler's standard library, say gcc's, the C++20 features are behind feature-specific preprocessor macros.)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

- Upgrade to a newer clangd. The latest released version is 11, and there are even newer weekly snapshot releases available on [Github](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/releases).
- If the crash persists, run clangd with `--log=verbose`, and file a [clangd issue](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues) with the log attached.